# Interacting with the ControlTemplate of the Embedded ToggleButton inside an Expander

Tags: silverlight, xaml, templates, controltemplate

I'm really hoping someone can teach me something new here, because there just has to be a cleaner route.

Inside the `Style` template of the toolkit's `Expander` control there's an embedded `ToggleButton` that handles the toggling of the Expander area. I'd like to find a better way to touch that specific UIElement without having to reiterate the entire style of the Expander. So for example, if this sits in the `Style` template of the `Expander`;

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="ExpanderButton"
              Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
              MinWidth="0" MinHeight="0"
              Margin="1"
              HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
              VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
              Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
              ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
              FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
              FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
              FontStretch="{TemplateBinding FontStretch}"
              FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}"
              FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}"
              Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
              IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsExpanded}"
              Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
              Template="{StaticResource TheExpanderToggleButtonStyle}" />
```

We see `Template="{StaticResource TheExpanderToggleButtonStyle}"` which just points to another separate `ControlTemplate` for that `ToggleButton` right? So I was hoping I could just do something at the instance level and just have a different template for just the ToggleButton and maybe reach it like;

```
<toolkit:Expander>
   <toolkit:Expander.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
          <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ADifferentToggleButtonStyle}"/>           
      </Style>
   </toolkit:Expander.Resources>

   <TextBlock Text="Blah"/>

</toolkit:Expander>
```

...or the same type of concept multiple different ways I could think of from something like that example that I didn't really expect to work anyway it just happened to be the last one I tried before posting, to trying to throw it at the header, to I dont even know how many different attempts, but to no avail. So I'm at the point of just copying both the damn templates just to make one custom Expander but like I said I hope someone can teach me a better way that would be really helpful in the future. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<toolkit:Expander
    my:ExpanderExtensions.ToggleButtonStyle="{StaticResource MyToggleBtnStyle}"/>
```

And the code:

```
public static class ExpanderExtensions
{
    public static Style GetToggleButtonStyle( Expander expander )
    {
        return (Style) expander.GetValue( ToggleButtonStyleProperty );
    }

    public static void SetToggleButtonStyle( Expander expander, Style value )
    {
        expander.SetValue( ToggleButtonStyleProperty, value );
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ToggleButtonStyleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached( "ToggleButtonStyle",
        typeof( Style ), typeof( ExpanderExtensions ),
                    new PropertyMetadata( OnToggleButtonStyleChanged ) );

    private static void OnToggleButtonStyleChanged(
                DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Expander expander = d as Expander;
        if (expander == null) return;

        if (expander.IsLoaded())
            ApplyToggleButtonStyle(expander, e.NewValue as Style);
        else
            expander.Loaded += OnExpanderLoaded;
    }

    private static void OnExpanderLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            Expander expander = (Expander) sender;
            expander.Loaded -= OnExpanderLoaded;
            ApplyToggleButtonStyle( expander, GetToggleButtonStyle(expander) );
    }

    private static void ApplyToggleButtonStyle(
                Expander expander, Style toggleButtonStyle)
    {
            //VisualTreeExtensions.GetVisualDescendants
            // is from System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit.dll
        var expanderToggleButton = expander.GetVisualDescendants().
                        OfType<ToggleButton>().First();
        expanderToggleButton.Style = toggleButtonStyle;
    }
}

public static class ControlExtensions
{
    public static bool IsLoaded(this FrameworkElement element)
    {
        return element.GetVisualChildren().Any();

        //I'm not sure if this alternative is better:
        //return control.GetVisualParent() != null;
    }
}
```

[Edit] You can set the `Template` via the `Style`, but if you don't want to set the Style just change the type of the attached property to `ControlTemplate` and adjust the `ApplyToggleButtonStyle` method.

Comment: Thanks Martin! Let me look over this when I have more time, I didn't really want to go the procedural route but may be a decent alternative.

Comment: @ChrisW. : I changed it slightly, now the `Loaded` event handler is detached once the event fired. About procedural versus declarative approach: Yes, I would prefer a public property _ToggleButtonStyle_ offered by the Expander control. But the original devs chose to not offer such an essential way for customization. I think my approach resembles that dream-solution and could be changed easily in the future in case of the unlikely event that an enhanced Expander is released in a new version of the Toolkit, offering such a property.